# Do redirects affect google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, 302-redirect

I have a website that redirects in the following manner:

1. https://example.com/drugs/paracetamol.html
2. http://example.com/drugs/new-paracetamol.html - 302
3. https://example.com/drugs/new-paracetamol.html - 302

I'm aware this is currently an issue and that the second redirect isn't necessary, it's a bug in the redirection config. However what I'm interested in is would this configuration currently affect google analytics results in any way? If so what would it affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how it would have any effect on Google Analytics. The tracking script only fires when a page is delivered to a browser.

The only way I can see this registering in Google Analytics is if you are using a client side redirect like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />` or redirecting with javascript.